# Process.Start() fails to open the exe

Tags: c#, .net

I'm trying to launch an application from c# code. Below is the code.. But the exe gives the error "Application has encountered a problem and needs to close. Sorry for the inconvenience".

I'm passing the command values as

```
command = "\"C:\\Program Files\\Nimbuzz\\Nimbuzz.exe\"";
```

code:

```
private int ExecuteSystemCommand(string command)
{
   procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + command);
   procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
   procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
   procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
   proc = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
   proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
   proc.Start();

   return proc.Id;
}
```

But the exe opens normally when opened from the desktop short cut. I dont know whats wrong. Please suggest.

Comment: Have you tried just passing `command` to the constructor instead of `cmd /c`?

Comment: Why do you need `cmd.exe` to call the exe indirectly instead of directly starting the exe?

Comment: Programs crash for all kinds of reasons, it surely has little to do with your C# code.  Minimize the odds of having trouble by executing it the way it's done from the shortcut.  Do not redirect output and set the ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory property.  Contact the program owner for support if that doesn't help.

Comment: Bet on WorkingDirectory!

Comment: @AlvinWong : your idea worked out.. Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well I just found out that, I need to set the Working directory first before calling the Process.Start()

```
Directory.SetCurrentDirectory("C:\\Program Files\\Nimbuzz\\");
```

Comment: I had the same issue after setting directory it works. Do you understand why for some processes you need to set current directory?

Comment: There is a better way to that which is to use `Process.Start()` overload and set `ProcessStartInfo.WorkingDirectory`. By calling `SetCurrentDirectory()` you change current directory of the running program as well (which might have consequence if you do some I/O operations like opening files using a relative path).

Answer (score 3):

You must specify the EXE you want to execute.

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", ...)
```

It would appear that these articles answer the question:

- [ProcessStartInfo.UseShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.useshellexecute.aspx)
- [ProcessStartInfo.FileName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processstartinfo.filename.aspx)